# Get list of a specific value of all the documents inside a subcollection in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having some problems dealing with subcollections  and fetching data to android.

My Firestore structure looks like this:

[image: Main collection]

and this is where I'm having problems:

[image: main collection and subcollection]

What I want: retrieve all the productID fields in the subcollection in order to use it in another query.
What I am stuck : HOW to actually do that? I've been stalking all the firestore related questions but I am only getting lost.
 this is what I've tried doing , and yes I'm working with RecylcerView :

```
 private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference panieref = db.collection("panier");
    private CollectionReference prodref = db.collection("products");
 private void setUpRecyclerView(){//for loading items from firestore
        final List<List<DocumentSnapshot>> productsList=new ArrayList<>();
        Query query =panieref.whereEqualTo("ID_del",newcom.getID_del());
        panieref.whereEqualTo("ID_del",newcom.getID_del()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                   for(final QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                     prodref.whereEqualTo("productID", Objects.requireNonNull(document.get("productID")).toString()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                         @Override
                         public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                             if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                 CollectionReference ProdColRef=panieref.document((String) Objects.requireNonNull(document.get("product_ID"))).collection("produits");

                                 productsList.add(task.getResult().getDocuments());
                             }
                         }
                     });

                   } }
            }
        });
        adapter= new detailsAdapter(productsList);
        //call up the recyclerview from the itemlist layout into the main activity layout
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.items_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Please Help, it's been a week and I've marked no progress and scrapped so many lines of code , I feel pretty useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're creating a reference to the products collection with:

```
private CollectionReference prodref = db.collection("products");
```

This means that Firestore looks for a top-level collection names `products`, which doesn't exist in your database as far as I can.

If you want the products collection from a specific `panier` document, you need to call `collection("products")` on that specific document:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference panieref = db.collection("panier");

final List<List<DocumentSnapshot>> productsList=new ArrayList<>();
Query query =panieref.whereEqualTo("ID_del",newcom.getID_del());
panieref.whereEqualTo("ID_del",newcom.getID_del()).get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull final Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

    if(task.isSuccessful()){
       for(final QueryDocumentSnapshot document : Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
         CollectionReference prodref = document.getReference().collection("products");

         prodref.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
             if(task.isSuccessful()){
               productsList.add(task.getResult().getDocuments());
             }
           }
         });
       } 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.